# Scanning input into a malloc pointer not working

Tags: c, input

I have this code but it's not working. No matter what I type it prints nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



char *askFile()
{
    printf("Enter a file: ");
    char *file = malloc(512 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", file);

    return file;
}



int main()
{
    char *file = askFile();
    printf("%s", *file);


    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: `*file` is the same as `file[0]`. It's the single first character in the string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oops, sorry I forgot about that C feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @Someprogrammerdude said in the comments the mistake was:

```
printf("%s", *file);
```

It was supposed to be:

```
printf("%s", file);
```

Since *file points to the first element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The key mistake is not using a good compiler with all warnings enabled.  A good well-enabled compiler would have warned about the specifier-type mismatch.

```
char *file =...;
printf("%s", *file); // Warning expected.
```

Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.